# Unable to create table in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'll post the two solutions I have tried, and what failed with each one:

First:

```
var table = document.createElement("table");
table.addClass("nice");
// fails because table does not have the "addClass" method
```

Second:

```
var table = $(document.createElement("table"));
table.addClass("nice");
var row = table.insertRow(-1);
// fails because table does not have the "insertRow" method (it has been cleared by jQuery)
```

How can I properly create a table and add rows and cells to it using jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var table = $('<table>')
  .addClass('nice');
```

To add rows, just create  elements and append them to the table.

Comment: Shouldn't be `$('<table />')` ?

Comment: @Alex - It doesn't matter, it's flexible.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to jQuery and didn't know I could do it like that. But does IE6 support this? I remember trying something like this (without jQuery, using document.createElement("tr")) and IE6 crashing or something like that. Anyway, antique browser, no one cares anymore. Thanks!

Comment: This is an old question, but how to set the `thead` part of the table ? I've beeen googling for a while withour succes :/

Comment: @Enissay you can add the `<thead>` section with `table.append($(`<thead/>`))`, or just `table.append('<thead/>');` - if you're still having trouble, post the code that's not working in a new question!

Answer (score 1):

```
var table = $('<table>').addClass('foo').append( $('<tr>').append( $('<td>').text('lol') ) ).appendTo('body')
```

It helps storing them in multiple variables, obviously.